Laravel Action Used As Job Is Not Implementing Silenced Interface
I have a laravel action which is being dispatched via command. AsJob trait is initialized in Action. Also it implements shouldQueue. I have also implemented Silenced Interface along with ShouldQueue. Also defined Action in silenced array in horizon.php. But its not working. Jobs can be seen in Completed and Failed Jobs On Horizon.
Tried horizon.php and implement ShouldQueue

Share your code.Show what you have done and what went wrong with your code. Without code nobody can assist you. And Silenced is a Contracts not an interface
